# Fatou lemma for $\{f_n+g_n \}$

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(E,\mathcal {A },\mu) $ be a finite measure space.

Take $\{f_n\}$ and $\{g_n\} $ two integrables sequences such that $\{f_n\}$ is positive.

Can we say that
$$
\int_E \liminf_n\big ( f_n+g_n\big )d\mu\leq  \liminf_n\int_E \big (f_n+g_n\big )d\mu
$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint,

Take $E=[0,2]$, $\mathcal A$ the Lebesgue measurable sets on $[0,2]$ and $\mu$ the lebesgue measure. What about if you take $g_n=-2f_n$ and $$f_n=\begin{cases}1_{[0,1]}&n\in 2\mathbb Z\\ 1_{[1,2]}&n\in 2\mathbb Z+1 \end{cases}\ \ ?$$